JavaFX App icon is not displayed in Dock on Ubuntu 24
My JavaFX application has stopped displaying the icon on Ubuntu 24, even though it worked perfectly on Ubuntu 22. JavaFX - 21. The icon is a 128x128 PNG and is set as follows:
public class MainFX extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Image icon = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/icon.png"));
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(icon);
    }

}

I've tried to use different icon sizes. This issue could be reproduced quite easily by creating a new project JavaFX in IDEA and trying to load icon using code above

Do you see the same problem using JavaFX 21.0.5 and/or JavaFX 23.0.1?

@Slaw, yes, I do. I've tried both, and the issue remains the same. It's frustrating because the behavior can be easily reproduced by simply creating a new JavaFX project in IntelliJ IDEA and attempting to load an icon. I've tested this on a fresh Ubuntu 24 VM.

jpackage resource directory launcher icon is platform-specific. It might be worth a try.
